# Copy/paste values in relation to a date (column) from sheet to another sheet with column of date

Tags: vba, excel

I´m new in VBA Excel. I´m trying to make a macro which is not difficult, but I´m so inexperienced.

I have sheet1 with column of dates (whole month), for each date there is different value. So column A is full of dates and column B is full of values (in relation with date). Sheet2/column A is also created by dates (whole month).

I would like to create a macro, which copy the value  from sheet1/column B and pass it to sheet2/column B according to date. In other words, the macro should find certain date (in sheet2/column A) and pass specific value to sheet2/column B.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Please provide a small example auf your data and your desired output. See also (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Couldn't this be done with a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you might need to change some values to match you workbook.
Like the sheets name and starting row on the for loop.

```
Sub sheetValues()

    'collect information in sheet one into an array
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        'check last filled in cell in column / last date
        Set last = .Range("A:A").Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        'new array with range information
        sheetOneInfo = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(last.Row, 2)).Value
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        'check last filled in cell in column / last date
        Set last = .Range("A:A").Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

        'for each cell in range
        For n = 1 To last.Row
            'if value in sheet two is in array
            If InArray(.Cells(n, 1).Value, sheetOneInfo) > 0 Then
                'put collected value in appropriate cell
                .Cells(n, 2).Value = sheetOneInfo(InArray(.Cells(n, 1).Value, sheetOneInfo), 2)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function InArray(val As String, arr As Variant) As Double

    InArray = 0
    'for each value in array
    For n = 1 To UBound(arr)
        'if date in array matches cell date
        If arr(n, 1) = val Then
            'return date position
            InArray = n
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this code below. You can change numbers 100 depending how many data you have or if it changes you can calculate it.

```
For i = 1 To 100
  For j = 1 To 100
    If Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) Then
      Sheets(2).Cells(j, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
    End If
  Next j
Next i
```